# Laravel Roles and permission manipulation

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I had a long read and application of the Laravel roles and permissions and was wondering if it's possible to remove the roles layer and directly assign permissions to users.

eg. instead of creating a role that has several permissions, roles_has_permissions, I could create users that has permission, user_has_permission.

In theory, it makes sense but in implementation, I am concerned with the fact that we are removing a layer that is an integral part of the said library. I couldn't find much information about such manipulation and I would really like some input and opinion on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

if you happen to use this package for roles and permission

> https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/basic-usage

The answer for your questions is a BIG YES".
Yes you can remove a certain or all the roles for a specific user or users.
Then just assign directly a permission for each user/users.
Especially in your scenario that you remove some specific permission in a roles. But some users still need that permission. You feel me?
So "YES" its possible, hope this help and and keep it up buddy.